# How to log insecure requests which don't have any Context?

Tags: java, spring, logging

I know how to log secure requests through token for Web and private key for Android, but I'm not able to log insecure requests!

So I have to build an Activity Logging Service for a project which has multiple platform i.e. Android and Web. Further I have two platforms for Web. In this logging service, Developers will be able to figure out time of request, caller function, security context holder, etc. I can do this for authenticated requests.

What to do for insecure requests which do not have any Security Context holder?